# How do I compute the angle between a pixel on an irregular curve and a circle colliding with it?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, level-design

I'm building a custom physics engine to accompany a level-editor. This image shows how the level-editor outputs levels:

[image]

Now, some explanation is in order. The curve is defined by the red points. After they are connected in threes by circles (yellow lines show these circles), a system connects them in a 'streamlined' way - as shown by the blue lines. This makes the curves flow seamlessly.

Now, these curves are 'irregular,' so to say. For the accompanying physics engine - how do I detect the angle made between a pixel on the curve and a colliding circle (per-pixel collision check)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37802/collision-detection-with-curves

Comment: I saw that post, but I'm not exactly dealing with bezier curves.

Comment: Wouldn't you just take the two adjacent pixels to form a line? Then you can calculate the "angle" between the pixel and colliding circle rather easily.

Comment: How `irregular` are your curves? Aren't they cubic splines? If you invented them and it doesn't bother you in sharing the idea, put the math online so we may help. I think there's an ocean on info on  spline-circle intersection out there. What did you look for before deciding it's not what you need/want?

Comment: @Byte56 I don't think that would work really. If you're taking adjacent pixels, you'll only have a handful different gradients (and hence, lines).

Comment: @teodron, When two yellow lines intersect, you move forward like this:

You first take 100% of the top curve, 0% from the bottom curve - that's the first pixel.
For the second one, you take 99% of the top curve, 1% from the bottom one. And you go one like that.

For example if the top curve's second pixel's y-coordinate is 100, and the bottom's is 0, the second curve would have y-coordinate 99.

Comment: Also, thanks to whoever edited the question to show the image inline. I didn't have sufficient reputation points to do that :)

Comment: Understood. Now, if your yellow curves are cubic splines, your blue one is a linear combination of those: `c(s) = (1-t)c1 + tc2`, where `t = (s-s_i)/(s_{i+1}-s_i)` and `s_i` are the nodes of the support interval of the splines (parameters space). It's still doable; @Byte56 's idea seems quite ok. Why wouldn't it work exactly? It's equivalent to computing the line `c(t0-e) -- c(t0+e)` where `t0` is parameter where the curve and circle intersect and `e` is an epsilon, small value.

Comment: The way I see @Byte56's solution, there can only 9 different lines, since you're only taking three adjacent pixels. Don't forget that pixels' coordinates are integers. Of course that can all be solved by using floats/doubles for the 'real' co-ordinates of the pixels.

Comment: It's probably safer to use floating point arithmetic and non-canvas intersection algorithms (it's mathematically saner). But still, if you have on pixel-wise queries, I only see one line to consider as a "contact surface". Will your engine work with pixels or real representations instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10358/discussion-between-teodron-and-memonick)